# Creating MonoTouch Custom Cells using XCode 4 does not work

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, custom-cell

I was used to creating Custom Cells in MonoTouch using Interface Builder but ever since XCode 4 has this integrated I can't seem to get it to work.
Is this a know issue?
Does anyone know of an article that describes how to go about this?  I have plenty of books and found articles about how this works in XCode 3 (Interface Builder) but I am looking at how this works in XCode 4 !!

Also, when creating iPad View Controllers in MonoTouch the files seem to be separated (I get an fHeader.cs and a fHeader.xib file) whereas before the fHeader.cs file was 'part of' the xib file (hierarchically below it).  Why is this?

I am using Mono 2.10.9 - XCode 4.2 and Monotouch 5.2.11

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has a nice tutorial:

http://blog.arcticmill.com/2012/05/uitableview-with-custom-uitableviewcell.html

Comment: I have seen this but the problem I am having is that when I create a new UIViewController in MT, then goto XCode 4, remove the default view and replace it with a UITableViewCell, then add some controls - create the outlets (ALSO one for the UITableViewCell) - then when I come back to MT and EVEN if I create an instance of this UIViewController from scratch then all the outlets default to null (it looks like they haven't been initialised...?)  I noticed when I copy and paste some old constructors that call Initialise() it does work!  Why do the new MT constructors not call Initialise() anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Check this tutorial:

http://sabonrai.wordpress.com/2009/08/28/monotouch-sample-code-uitableview/

Normally you create a DataSource Delegate and there you override the `GetCell` function.

In this function you can create your custom cell.